# Move overflowed elements to another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with fixed height and another div below it with fixed height. I want elements (whole elements) that cannot fit within first div to move to another div. I don't want elements to be cut- just moved in whole and I want the order to be kept- so span2 will never be before (higher) than span1.

```
<div id="div1" style="height: 200px; width: 300px">
<span id="span1">Hello world<span>
<span id="span2">El 1</span>
</div>

<div id="div2" style="height:200px; width: 300px"></div>
```

Is this possible with just CSS? It doesn't really have to move from div1 to div2. I need just 2 containers of fixed height and moving elements between them. Can this be done with CSS columns? Or flex?

[JS FIDDLE:](http://jsfiddle.net/hnxrLav8/)

Comment: if you mean having #span2 a child of #div2, this can't be done with just CSS: CSS doesn't change the DOM

Comment: @DenysSéguret I know it cannot. But perhaps what I want to achieve can be done with CSS columns (or something like this)? So it looks live 2 different divs but it's really just 1.

Comment: You can achieve this by jquery, By removing the existing DIV, and recreating it where you wanted it needed to be.

Comment: @Mayank With jQuery I need to first calculate position and height of every child in div1 and then move all the overflowed ones to div2. Since I let user dynamically change text of elements in div1 I would need to bring all the elements back from div2 to div2 after user edits anything and then recalculate positions and move again to div2. That seems like a slow option.

Comment: why not just make the elements fixed width and `display:inline-block`? then they would make as many columns as would fit and then reflow below just like any normal inline element.

Comment: @nonchip Because I need to have a visible separation between the upper block and lower block. If I use display: inline-block then I won't have a separation.

Comment: well you could use margins and/or absolute positioned divs if you need a border too

Comment: @nonchip Well, I can't. There are multiple items in div1. They have different heights. User can enter text in these items. Once there is so much items that they don't fit in div1 I want them to go to div2. Of course they can in fact stay in div1 but I need to show a visible separator between what fits and what doesn't fit in div1.

Comment: i'm afraid then you have to calculate the sizes in js and then move the dom elements around

Comment: did you solved that ? Can you FIDDLE the problem..

Comment: @Mayank I didn't yet. I added JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hnxrLav8/

Answer (score 2):

Try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hnxrLav8/6/).

Following code checks the DIV overflow status.

**Javascript:**

```
function IsDivOverFlow(div)
{
    if (div.outerHeight() < div.prop('scrollHeight') || div.outerWidth() < div.prop('scrollWidth')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Using the function on **button click**

```
var Count = 0;
$('button').click(function()
{
    var EditableContent = '<span contenteditable=true>'+(++Count)+' : TEST</span>';
    var oldHTML = $('#div1').html();
    $('#div1').append(EditableContent);
    if(IsDivOverFlow($('#div1'))){
        $('#div1').html(oldHTML);
        $('#div2').append(EditableContent);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use css columns you can use something like this, but only using one div instead of two:

```css
.your_class{
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
```

Comment: But I can put second column below first one instead of next to first one?

Comment: that's called rows not columns